# Share base64 with expo-sharing

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a base64 code that is a QR code and I want to share it on social networks with
expo-sharing.
But i can’t find a way to do it, i know it only accepts url, so try using expo FileSystem to download a cached file and get url, but the error remains the same, I don’t know how to use the downloadAsync method with base64 code, does anyone have any idea how to do it?